# Reset password in community using System.ResetPassword referring another community

Tags: apex, community, reset-password

I have a community user who has access to multiple communities.
What I am doing is, calling `System.ResetPassword(userId, true)` from a guest user context.

So the reset password link is sent to the registered email of the external user.

The issue is, the reset link domain is another community site. For example, I am requesting to reset the password from `community A`, but my reset password link refers to `community B`.

I can use `System.resetPassword(userId, true, emailTemplate)`
But, I think, it will not solve the problem. Because the merge fields cannot decide which community fields it is referring to. Below is my emailTemplate.

```
Hi {!Receiving_User.FirstName}, 
Your password has been reset for {!Community_Name}. 
Please click the button below to create a new password for your account.
<a href="{!Community_Url}" target="_blank">Create a new password</a>

Thanks
```

How can I make sure the `{!Community_Name}` and `{!Community_Url}` are the right ones?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Communities Welcome Email - Set Password link not working ({!Community\_URL})](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/63417/communities-welcome-email-set-password-link-not-working-community-url)

Comment: No, it doesn't answer. Context is different here.

Comment: Any idea @sfdcfox?